# Get string value from Placeholder C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, matching

I have pattern string:"**Hello {Name}, welcome to {Country}**"
and a full value string:"**Hello Scott, welcome to VietNam**"
How can I extract value of {Name} and {Country}:
*Name = Scott, Country = VietNam*
I have see some regular expression to resolve this problem but can I apply fuzzy matching here?
 e.g. With invert string "**welcome to VietNam, Hello Scott**", we must change the regular expression too?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't include minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have tried using regular expression but actual question is how to extract value in general way with less of changing expression

Comment: @phuongnd Updated answer, it will work both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a more general solution, you can do something like the following:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetMatches(string pattern, string source)
{
    var tokens = new List<string>();
    var matches = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    pattern = Regex.Escape(pattern);

    pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\\{.*?}", (match) =>
        {
            var name = match.Value.Substring(2, match.Value.Length - 3);

            tokens.add(name);

            return $"(?<{name}>.*)";
        });

    var sourceMatches = Regex.Matches(source, pattern);

    foreach (var name in tokens)
    {
        matches[name] = sourceMatches[0].Groups[name].Value;
    }

    return matches;
}
```

The method extracts the token names from the pattern, then replaces the tokens with the equivalent syntax for a regular expression named capture group.  Next, it uses the modified pattern as a regular expression to extract the values from the source string.  Finally, it uses the captured token names with the named capture groups to build a dictionary to be returned.

Comment: Best ever seen solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regex:

```
var Matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"hello\s+?([^\s]*)\s*|welcome\s+?to\s+?([^\s]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string Name = Matches.Groups[1].Value;
string Country  = Matches.Groups[2].Value;
```

**Update:** Changed code to work either way. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oY6sI2/2).

Comment: Better yet, use a regular expression to extract the tokens from the template and build a new regular expression where the original tokens are replaced with named capture groups and the rest of the string is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Just quick and dirty..

```
string pattern = "Hello Scott, welcome to VietNam";

var splitsArray = pattern.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var Name = splitsArray[1].Replace(",", string.Empty);
var country = splitsArray[4];
```